# How to wait all coroutine finished in lua just like waitgroup in go?

Tags: lua, synchronization, coroutine

How to wait all coroutine finished in lua just like waitgroup in go? Waitgroup in go is completed with Semaphobe. But how to complete it in lua? Or any better scheme?

Comment: What means `to wait`?  In Lua coroutines are collaborative (at any given time, only one coroutine runs).  In golang, they are indeed parallel & simultaneous.

Answer (score 3):

Lua is not a threaded scripting language. It has no concept of multiple things being able to happen at once (you can have multiple independent Lua states executing on distinct threads, but they're *different* Lua states. If you want them to be able to talk to each other, then you have to provide the means to do so manually).

As such, a Lua coroutine is simply a function which can choose to suspend its execution, returning some number of values to the function which invoked the coroutine. The user can then resume the coroutine, allowing it to further perform some task. This is cooperative multitasking; a task suspends execution only when it *chooses to*. This is in contrast to pre-emptive multitasking, where a task can just stop executing or execute in parallel with something else.

Given this, the idea of "waiting" for a coroutine or group of coroutines simply doesn't make sense. You *resume* a coroutine when you want it to execute further; it's not a passive action.

You could certainly create a list of coroutines and resume each one in turn repeatedly until all of them have terminated. But there's no Lua standard library function to do that, because it's generally not useful for the uses coroutines perform.